# How to report bugs, give suggestions and feedback on Sharepoint, SPD, Infopath?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath, administration, forms-services

I am continuously bumping against annoying bugs (and/or inconveniencies "by design") in Sharepoint Server 2010, its related tools and services like:

- Infopath Designer 2010,
- Microsoft Sharepoint 2010 Central Administration
- Infopath Forms Services
- Sharepoint Designer 2010
- etc.

So, I logged in to https://connect.microsoft.com with intention to provide )some of my) feedback.
https://connect.microsoft.com/directory/ doesn't contain anything with either of words:

- **sharepoint** or
- **infopath**

(Internal) Search there by any of these words gives:

- There are no records that match the requested criteria

Googling by any of these words in site:connect.microsoft.com  gives a lot of feedback/suggestion/bug reports but mostly under:

- Visual Studio and .NET Framework
- SQL Server

I am lost...
Where to report bugs and provide feed back to Microsoft about its Sharepoint Server 2010, Infopath Designer 2010, Sharepoint Designer 2010 unrelated to MSSQL or VS?

Or I should start learning how to crack internals of Sharepoint Server pack?

**Update:**
I want to offer my time, work as tester for reporting bugs and to provide suggestions/feedback and hear "Please visit the below link to see the various paid support", i.e to pay for possibility to invest my time and efforts?!

Answer (score 2):

It seems Microsoft is not accepting feedback for SharePoint Server 2010. But, if you have MSDN subscription you can open the Support Case and report bugs to Microsoft. Depending on type of subscription, you get number of support cases you can open.

Comment: I am dev. I do not buy anything my employers and clients do... or do not. I have no idea, I am not intelligence agent under cover to make investigations or push inquiries. Besides, I am just now more interested in Infopath and SPD

Comment: Some employers do buy their developers with MSDN subscriptions. I'm not sure if this is true in your case.

Comment: I am not employee, I am free-lancer and work remotely over internet in a virtual machine of my client

Comment: Please visit the below link to see the various paid support options that are available to better meet your needs: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?id=fh;en-us;offerprophone. If you are a MSDN / TechNet subscriber, you can also contact our support by using your free support incidents.

Comment: I do not need support, especially in unwarranted by me language and paid one. I work with all software in English but the site is in Russian, it is additional headache to translate and switch between languages for no special reason except someone thinks it is more funny to decide for others. I just want to report the problem in order to save the time to others and proceed in my work in a more systematic way